# Page shifts to right when a hidden div is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using css3, html5 and javascript to build a page. There is a div which is hidden at the start and is visible only when the user selets a check box. What is happenning is that when I select the check box the whole page shifts to right and on deselecting the checkbox it returns to its normal position (shifts left). I am encountering it on both chrome and IE. I am not sure whats causing it as the margin, border and padding appears to be same when selecting the checkbox. Also when I open the developer's console by pressing F12, the shifting does not happen. It only ocurs when the page is maximized. The code is:

Javascript

```
$('#IsPropertyHandedOver').change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('#HandoverYesDiv').prop('hidden', false);
    } else {
        $('#HandoverYesDiv').prop('hidden', true);
    }
});
```

css

```
textarea.form-control{
height: 20em;
}

input[readonly] {
  cursor: default !important;
}

textarea[readonly]{
    cursor:default !important;
}

#addedNote{
height: 10em !important;
resize: none;
}

.field-validation-error{
    color:red
}

fieldset.scheduler-border {
border: 1px groove #ddd !important;
padding: 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
box-shadow:  0px 0px 0px 0px #000;
}

legend.scheduler-border {
    font-size: 1.2em !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    width:auto;
    padding:0 10px;
    border-bottom:none;
}

.panel-inside-form .panel-body{
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
}


.panel-inside-form input[type="text"]{
    /*border-color:black;*/
    margin-bottom:1em;
    border-color:rgb(169,169,169);
}

.panel-inside-form textarea{
    /*border-color:black;*/
    margin-bottom:1em;
    border-color:rgb(169,169,169);
}

.panel-inside-form select{
    /*border-color:black;*/
    margin-bottom:1em;
    border-color:rgb(169,169,169);
}

.panel-inside-form input[type="checkbox"]{
    /*border-color:black;*/
    margin-bottom:1em;
}

select.input-validation-error{
    border-color:lightcoral
}

input[type="text"].input-validation-error{
    border-color:lightcoral
}

textarea.input-validation-error{
    border-color:lightcoral
}

.form-group.required .control-label:after { 
   content:" *";
   color:red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="HandoverYesDiv" hidden>
    <div class="form-group form-group-check">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsKeysHandedOver, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsKeysHandedOver)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EventId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsHandoverCompleted)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-check">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsSafetyCertificatesHandevOver, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSafetyCertificatesHandevOver)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-check">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsInstructionsOrManualsHandedOver, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsInstructionsOrManualsHandedOver)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-check">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsLegionellaCheckPerformed, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsLegionellaCheckPerformed)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IsLegionellaCheckPerformed)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it not perhaps that when you show the hidden div, the page content becomes long enough for the browser's scroll bar to appear and so the content seemingly shifts to account for the smaller viewport? Try force the scrollbar to always be present. I forgot how to do this and it's bed time now but hope this helps...

Comment: https://www.screenr.com/M2QN

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is connected with the [positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) through css.
What about inserting `position: relative` in the css related to the element that contains `HandoverYesDiv`, while this one should be written as `absolute`?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your CSS.

```
#HandoverYesDiv {
 position: absolute;   
}
```

Comment: this has kept the div position as fixed but the controls inside the div appears all over the page when the checkbox is selected.

Comment: Maybe you have to add `float: left` to your other elements, I think the elements goes down (new line) from the page since they are not fit on the current screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use the css-property `display` if you want to completely hide DOM-elements.

Replace

```
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('#HandoverYesDiv').prop('hidden', false);
} else {
    $('#HandoverYesDiv').prop('hidden', true);
}
```

With

```
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('#HandoverYesDiv').css('display', '');
} else {
    $('#HandoverYesDiv').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: this does not show the div on selecting the checkbox.